Does length contraction "break the speed limit"? Part 2
This is a follow-up to another question I asked here:
Does length contraction "break the speed limit"?
The answer to that question was "nothing is moving faster than light, the observer is just changing their reference frame." But now I've thought of a reformulation of the question in which the observer stays in an inertial frame, so I'm confused again. Here's the new scenario:
Suppose I'm on Earth (or floating nearby, I don't want to worry about gravitational effects here), and my friend Alice is next to me in a spaceship at rest (relative to me). My friend Bob is in a similar spaceship by the planet Zorbulax, which is $100$ light-years away and happens to also be perfectly at rest compared to Earth. Bob's ship is pointed towards Earth, and Alice's ship is pointed directly away from Zorbulax.
Now, Alice and Bob both start their engines and rapidly accelerate to ~$95$% the speed of light, then cut their engines and continue at that velocity. That means from my point of view they experience a ~$10$x time dilation (if my math's right). But that means they also experience a ~$10$x length contraction.
Now my understanding is that this length contraction applies not only to Alice and Bob's ships, but also to the distance between their ships. This must be the case, since once they cut their engines we could also view the situation as me traveling from Alice to Bob at $.95c$. But they're on opposite sides of me, and I'm now observing them as only ~$10$ light-years apart - does that mean that Bob has now traveled ~$90$ light-years in a short amount of time, meaning he went faster than light relative to me?
Unlike the last question, I never accelerated - I'm in a completely inertial frame of reference, so "changed reference frame" can't be the answer here, can it? Am I misunderstanding length contraction? Or maybe there's something tricky going on with relativity of simultaneity and the amount of time Bob's been traveling isn't what I think it is? Please help me get an intuition for what's happening here!

No that cannot be true and you dont need the math to explain it.No object can move at a speed greater than c.It is one of the postulates of SR.There is a error in your logic 102%

@RootGroves To be clear, my question isn't "Is there an error in my logic?", it's "Where is the error in my logic?"

Hint:the error is in this paragraph:"Now my understanding is that this length contraction applies not only to Alice and Bob's ships, but also to the distance between their ships. This must be the case, since once they cut their engines we could also view the situation as me traveling from Alice to Bob at .95c
. But they're on opposite sides of me, and I'm now observing them as only ~10
light-years apart - does that mean that Bob has now traveled ~90
light-years in a short amount of time, meaning he went faster than light relative to me?"

You are forgetting about the relativity of simultaneity. The two spaceships have moved into a new frame in which their distance apart is now greater than it was before they started accelerating. Try to figure it out. It is related to Bell’s rocket paradox.

The ships remain the same distance apart in the Earth frame because they are accelerating in synch in that frame. Length contraction does apply to the distance between them, ergo they must be much further apart in their new rest frame.

In their new rest frame, the leading ship started to accelerate much earlier than the trailing ship did, and hence the gap between them widened.

It is this part “I'm now observing them as only ~10 light-years apart”. No, in your frame (inertial) they are still about 100 ly apart

This problem will be trivial to understand if you had instead opted to draw some Minkowski diagrams.

@ProfessorSushing I laugh every time someone says to a newbie "you are forgetting . . . (ROS)" ;)   I guarantee you the OP has not forgotten!

As @naturallyInconsistent points out, drawing spacetime diagrams is the way forward.  If you can't draw a diagram, then you don't even understand the question yourself (way more important than naming planets).

@m4r35n357 Well, the question is, "What am I misunderstanding about this situation?" When I write out a scenario in which something goes faster than light, I clearly am not understanding something in it! But through the various comments here, I believe it's that I missed a key difference between this question and the first one, which is when Alice and Bob each started accelerating, and that difference leads to length contraction in the first question but no length contraction here.

The thing you are "misunderstanding" is the need to draw a diagram.  Alice & Bob don't excite anyone much these days, also I am personally opposed to the whole idea of teaching SR as "time dilation + woo".  There are better ways, and I have attempted to point you there!

If I've understood your question correctly, it has nothing to do with relativity.  Relativity allows you to compare how things look in one frame with how things look in another frame.  But your question (again, if I've understood correctly) is entirely about how things look in a single frame (namely yours).
In that frame, Alice and Bob start off 100 light years apart.  At every instant, they are both traveling at the same speed in the same direction.  There is therefore no way the distance between them can change.
Continuing to view everything from your frame, the lengths of their ships might or might not change, depending on exactly how they accelerate.  If the front ends of their ships accelerate before the back ends do, the ships will get longer.  If the front and back ends accelerate simultaneously, the ships' lengths won't change.  If the back ends accelerate first, the ships will get shorter.
No matter what, once the ships are moving, they will always be shorter in your frame than they are in Bob's and Alice's.  That's a comparison across frames and you need relativity to discover it.  But everything else, including the distance between the ships, is a question about your frame only, where simple mathematics tells you that if two things consistently mimic each others' velocities, the distance between those things cannot change.

Let me ask a couple questions to clarify: Suppose I'm traveling from Earth to Zorbulax at .$95$c. 1) Will I observe the planets to be length-contracted by about ~$10$x of how they see themselves? 2) Will I observe the distance from Earth to Zorbulax to be length-contracted ~$10$x compared to the distance someone on the planet observes?

Yes and yes....because in your frame, Zorbulax started moving toward you quite a long time ago and the earth started moving away from you much more recently, so the distance between them shrank.  But in your original scenario, in your frame, Bob and Alice started moving simultaneously, so the two scenarios are fundamentally different.

Okay, but now let's use some relativity. That set-up is the exact same as the one where Alice and Bob are moving in the Zorbulax-to-Earth direction at .95c and I'm at rest! (Just with the planets replaced by spaceships.) So shouldn't I still see the length contraction on the distance between them?

@DanStaley: Your second comment and my first comment appeared simultaneously.  I believe my first comment answers your second.

Okay, so I think this is a relativity of simultaneity thing... I need to think through this a bit more.

@DanStaley:  As you think this through, keep in mind that the only way a thing can shrink is for one end of it to start moving before the other does.  That definitely makes all your questions entirely dependent on what is and is not simultaneous in a given frame.

I just realized my first comment could be misleading.  A better way to say it:  In your new scenario, in your new frame, Zorbulax and Earth are and have always been 10 light years apart.  They have both always been moving at the same velocity, so that distance has never changed.  In your original scenario, in your original frame, Bob and Alice are and have always been (and as far as we know, will always be) 100 light years apart.  They have both always been moving at the same velocity, so that distance has never changed.  The two scenarios are not as different as I made them sound.

Hilariously, you mentioned yourself they are both moving 95% the speed of light, so obviously they aren't moving faster than light.
But to actually answer your question, the length of the whole universe does not change just because Alice and Bob are flying in their rockets. You may be having trouble perceiving what length contraction actually is. Length contraction is a "relative" thing hence the name "relativity."
The space around you looks normal to you, but Alice and Bob are going to appear compressed in size, they are going to look smaller to you. They aren't going to appear $10$-light years apart, they are going to appear $10$-times smaller in the direction of motion.
Important note here is that length contraction affects how long the rockets appear to you, but not how fast they are moving relative to you. They are both moving at 0.95 times the speed of light relative to you.

What if Alice and Bob were in one ridiculous, 100-light-year-long ship? Would that still contract, effectively bringing Bob (in the rear) closer to me?

@DanStaley:  In order for that 100-light-year-long ship to contract in your frame, the back must start moving before the front does (again in your frame).  Yes, that brings Bob closer to you.  You don't need relativity to see any of this.

What Will said is actually what I pretty much said in the discussion room a few minutes ago, ftr :)


Now, Alice and Bob both start their engines and rapidly accelerate to ~95% the speed of light, then cut their engines and continue at that velocity. That means from my point of view they experience a ~10x time dilation (if my math's right). But that means they also experience a ~10x length contraction.


Now my understanding is that this length contraction applies not only to Alice and Bob's ships, but also to the distance between their ships…

Everything here is technically correct, except for your understanding of length contraction. You do not observe the distance between them getting shorter (although they might, depending on the particulars). If we pick some frame $\mathcal{F}$, bring us all at rest in that frame, and then Alice and Bob fly off in opposite directions so that they have great speed relative to us (at rest in $\mathcal{F}$), the distance that we measure between them is unaffected by their motion because we, the measures, are still at rest in $\mathcal{F}$. They are no longer at rest in $\mathcal{F}$, so their distance measurements will vary, but we still are at rest, so ours remain as they should be.
We could also call $\mathcal{G}$ Alice’s new rest frame and ask what the relative velocity is for Bob in that frame, and say that she sees Bob moving at ~140% lightspeed, but you can’t add velocities simply like that. The Lorentz transformation adds rapidities, not velocities, and transforming from $\mathcal{F}$ to $\mathcal{G}$ never ends up sending Bob away faster than light.

I'm still confused. Forget Bob and the acceleration for a second. Suppose Alice is flying past me at .95c in a ship that's 100 meters long from her point of view. Don't I observe her ship as 10 meters long, just as she observes me 10 times shorter in the direction of travel? And then, if there's another ship 100 meters behind her (from her point of view) going the same speed, won't I see it as 10 meters behind her?

So a ship is following her at the same speed? - no, you don’t observe the distance between them to be length-contracted, only the physical shapes of the ships themselves (unless I’m misunderstanding.)

One thing I think you missed - Alice is traveling away from us, Bob is traveling toward us. So at the end of the thought experiment they are moving at the same velocity.

Oh, whoops - I think the same result applies though. Lorentz transforming between any of the frames never ends up bringing anyone FTL.

I really think you're getting length contraction wrong here. You say the atoms at the end of her ship appear 10 meters from the atoms at the front of her ship, so clearly the space between them is contracted. Why is that space any different than the space between ships? What if she throws a baseball backwards from the front of her ship - does it suddenly seem to start moving away from the ship more quickly once it passes the end of it?

Consider the case where that distance is contracted. Let’s say I stand next to a volcano, a kilometer away so it’s safe. In some arbitrary frame, the distance between me and the volcano would be contracted to one millimeter, so someone in that frame should see me burst into flames. But that’s not consistent with me not bursting into flames in my rest frame, so there would be Lorentz symmetry breaking now that there’s a “true” reference frame. Conversely, if physical distance isn’t contracted, there’s no issue.

If you think about your comment a bit, it appears you just made an argument that length contraction cannot exist at all in any frame of reference, which is definitely not what relativity says. In the frame in which I'm a millimeter away, time is dilated by a factor of many thousands. The volcano doesn't have enough energy to push its heat across the millimeter in such a dilated timeframe; this is just like how it takes more and more energy to accelerate as you approach light speed.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
